# Need clarification on delegates in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

As per Apple documentation:

> Delegation is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object in a
>   program acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object.
>   The delegating object keeps a reference to the other object—the
>   delegate—and at the appropriate time sends a message to it.

Please clarify.  In the case of `UIAlertView`, is `UIAlertView` is delegating object?

Comment: What is unclear example?

Comment: For UIAlertView the delegate would be the object that takes an action depending on the user selection, if any is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `UIAlertView`, yes, `UIAlertView` is a delegating object and whatever its `delegate` property points to is its delegate.

For everything in Apple's built-in frameworks, the delegating object will typically have a property called `delegate`.  The delegating object is the one which has this property (which is where it holds the reference to its delegate).  The delegate is the object to which the `delegate` property points.

In addition to this, some of Apple's classes, such as `UITableView` (there are plenty of others too), will additionally have a `datasource` property.  `UITableView` holds the same sort of relationship with its datasource as it does with its delegate.

Technically speaking, in both cases, `UITableView` is the delegating object, and both the `delegate` and the `datasource` (which can point to different objects) point to the "delegate" objects.

Realistically speaking, we would never refer to `UITableView`'s `datasource` object as being its "delegate"--we'd call it its datasource.  This prevents confusion between which object is the datasource and which object is the delegate.

Also, keep in mind that just because something is a delegating object doesn't mean it can't also be something else's delegate.